# MbUnit Integration Testing Newbie Question

Tags: c#, com, integration, mbunit

I've been tasked with integration testing  of a large system. Presently, I have a COM dll that I'm testing useing a UI that I created that kicks off a series of unit tests that call into the dll. This works, but I'm wanting to migrate this over to MbUnit. When I start the first test in MbUnit, it seems to hang at "Found 1 tests". I end up having to close the IDE. Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This is how we kick off our MBUnit test application (command line):

```
namespace UnitTest
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args_)
    {
      // run unit test
      AutoRunner auto = new AutoRunner();
      auto.Load();
      auto.Run();

      HtmlReport report = new HtmlReport();

      string fileName;
      // generate report results
      fileName = report.Render(auto.Result);

      // launch results in user's browser
      System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(fileName);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try stepping through the code manually with a debugger.